# How to solve this JSX error in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, typescript, react-native

Getting the below error on a new TS file containing JSX for React native:

```
Unexpected token, expected ","
```

Below is the code for the component I'm making. The error appears to

```
class TabLabel extends React.PureComponent<IReactionsLabelProps> {
    constructor(props: IReactionsLabelProps) {
        super(props);
    }

    render = () => {
        const { name, baseUrl, getCustomEmoji, reactions, page, theme } = this.props;

        return (
            <View style={ sharedStyles.tabView }>
                <Emoji
                    content={name}
                    standardEmojiStyle={sharedStyles.reactionEmoji}
                    customEmojiStyle={sharedStyles.reactionCustomEmoji}
                    baseUrl={baseUrl}
                    getCustomEmoji={getCustomEmoji}
                />
                <Text style={{
                    ...sharedStyles.textBold, color: themes[theme].bodyText
                }}>
                    { reactions[page]?.usernames?.length }
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

The linter provides a different error near the "style" prop in the first line of the JSX:
Parsing error: '>' expected

I am completely stuck and have no idea what's going wrong.
Full file is available at https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat.ReactNative/blob/b1f9916ed8f9a423e356987d934998a139809627/app/views/ReactionsView/index.ts#L45

Complete error below: [image: error code]

Comment: Can you give the complete error including line number?

Comment: Try changing your Text style to `[sharedStyles.textBold, { color: themes[theme].bodyText }]`.

Comment: @Dan That was the original. Changed it to what you see now to try to resolve the error.

Comment: Unrelated, but why an instance property function here instead of a prototype function? No biggie, but seems unnecessarily redundant in this case.

Comment: @DaveNewton Redundant indeed. Was a desperate attempt in changing something and getting it to work, but to no avail.

Comment: Is the only error? I don't see any non-printables in the raw source. My first approach would be to simply create a new file with just the imports required to create a component that returns another `<View>`, and build it up until the error shows up. If it's a syntax error it's not an obvious one so just rebuild it until the error shows up.

Comment: I guess I'll just have to do that. Feels extremely weird though. The thing is even the VSCode highlighter shows something's wrong. Wish there was a way to put a debugger on the highlighter.... I'll update if i find the error.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question. And I feel exceedingly dumb now, needless to say, having spent literal hours trying to solve this.

Just had to change the extension of the file from .ts to .tsx, and it worked.